# php select items query from table1, copy to table2

Tags: php, mysql

I want to arrange my `articles` from database.

How to make a page function that first query and print all the `articles' titles` in one page.

then before every `article title`, create a select box (like gamil e-mail system. select all e-mails than mave delete or other thing, here I just want to copy my articles to another database)

I am not sure how to make such a select function, could select the articles what I need manual, then just click one confirm button, copy the database.

can any one give me some advice? Maybe should use jQuery or other tools...

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $db)
 $querys = ("SELECT * FROM table1");
$results = mysql_query($querys);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resulst)) { ?>
<li><a class="select"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></a></li>
<?php }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your specific implementation details are a little hazy, but in terms of MySQL, you could do something like this once you know which article id's you want to copy:

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE article_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6);
```